# Descrese my WordPress Custom Field on WPForm submit

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, acfpro

I have a problem with my site where I created CPT which is called "Events" which I populated with ACF where I create name of event, date, artist, description and number_of_people where I enter number of people which can come to event (something like registration for that event). Now I created Elementor single post page for my Events where I placed my WPForm which I use for registration. Now, I want for every registration to reduce number of available tickets.

```
add_action('wpforms_process_complete', 'reduce_custom_field_on_form_submission', 10, 4);
function reduce_custom_field_on_form_submission($form_id, $entry_id, $form_data, $entry_data) {
    if ($form_id == 56797) {
        $post_id = $entry_data['post_id'];
        $custom_field_name = 'number_of_people';
        $amount_to_reduce = 1;

        $current_value = get_field($custom_field_name, $post_id);

        if ($current_value !== false) {
            $new_value = max(0, $current_value - $amount_to_reduce);
            
            update_field($custom_field_name, $new_value, $post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're using the hook `wpforms_process_complete` incorrectly.  Looking at their docs on https://wpforms.com/developers/wpforms_process_complete/ it cites an example of their function.  I don't use WP Forms, so I can't test this, but check the form field ID of the field you're after, and replace where I commented it. [6] is the number to replace.

```
add_action( 'wpforms_process_complete', 'reduce_custom_field_on_form_submission', 10, 4 );
function reduce_custom_field_on_form_submission( array $fields, array $entry, array $form_data, int $entry_id ) {
    if ( 56797 === absint( $form_data['id'] ) ) {
        // Get the full entry object.
        $entry = wpforms()->entry->get( $entry_id );

        // Fields are in JSON, so we decode to an array.
        $entry_fields = json_decode( $entry->fields, true );
        // Entry Fields are done by field ID from the form builder. Replace [6] with whatever your field's number is.
        $post_id = $entry_fields[6]['value'];

        $current_value = get_field( 'number_of_people', $post_id );

        if ( false !== $current_value ) {
            $new_value = max( 0, $current_value - 1 );

            update_field( 'number_of_people', $new_value, $post_id );
        }
    }
}
```